# Understanding terminology used to describe the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, metalanguage

This might seem a bit of an odd question, but I'm grappling with the DOM right now and trying to make sense of its structure.  Much of the language that is used to describe its constructs are a little confusing to me as I try to visualize the DOM more concretely.

It seems the preposition "on" is often used to describe the relationship between properties and objects. For example, a question posed to this forum asks "Why do Dom-elements exist as properties on the window object". A respondent writes "...the HTML5 specifies that elements are candidates to be directly exposed as properties on the window object...".

This bothers me. Why 'on'? I hate to be so persnickety, but aren't properties "*of*" an object?  Or found "*in*" an object?  Or "*inherited by*" or "*from*" another object?  When are properties '*on*' an object? So there must be some significance of the use of the preposition 'on' to describe something of which I am unaware. There is also reference to properties or objects being "attached" to an object, which I suspect means the same thing.

Comment: since _window_ is implicit, _on_ might be a subtle way of describing such pseudo-globals, but there's no standard answer afaik, "would a rose by any other name not smell so sweet?" It might also allude to their existence elsewhere, thus making them not "own properties" members like the usual for-of would hit.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking the issue. Objects "have" properties. They possess them; they own them; they sport them; they expose them; they support them. The underlying reality is pretty simple.

Comment: Replace "on" with "of" and you're done. There is a lot of jargon in IT, sometimes misplaced, sometimes not strictly in accordance with the specification but you should probably just roll with it unless there's a chance of confusion or ambiguity (e.g. *this* and *context*, *JSON* and "*json object*", HTML element vs tag).

Comment: @RobG That's what I suspected, but wasn't certain if I might be missing something, perhaps having to do with inheritance, and if the use of 'on' was intentional and had some other meaning.